# Sending Email With Attachment Through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I would like to email a report through Outlook from Excel.

I am testing this with my own and coworkers' email address. I get an "Undeliverable" **`Error`**.

The message says the recipient cannot be reached and suggests trying to send the email later.

```
Sub CreateEmail()

Dim OlApp As Object
Dim OlMail As Object
Dim ToRecipient As Variant
Dim CcRecipient As Variant

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(olmailitem)

For Each ToRecipient In Array("jon.doe@aol.com")
    OlMail.Recipients.Add ToRecipient
Next ToRecipient

For Each CcRecipient In Array("jon.doe@aol.com")
    With OlMail.Recipients.Add(CcRecipient)
        .Type = olCC
    End With
Next CcRecipient

'Fill in Subject field
OlMail.Subject = "Open Payable Receivable"

'Add the report as an attachment
OlMail.Attachments.Add ("C:\OpenPayRecPrint2.pdf")

'Send Message
OlMail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel VBA doesn't know the value of `olCC`. If you make the Outlook app visible and comment out the Send line you might be able to more easily figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Tim - Excel VBA would know the value of olCc if OP has set a reference to the Outlook Object Library.

Comment: @Tim Williams Thank you for your insight, I used apostrophes infront of the CC section and I was able to send the email. Is there any way I can set up a CC list within my current code that you are familiar with? Do I need to establish olCC in the "Set.." area?

Comment: If you are using late binding, the numeric values for the named constants are olMailItem=0, olTo=1, olCC=2. Use the numeric values instead of the named constant.

Comment: @Michael - you can add `Const olTo = 1` and `Const olCC = 2` at the top of your Sub. Likewise for `olMailItem`

Comment: @TimWilliams , ChipsLetten - Thank you both for the insight, I apologize, this is my first time using VBA with OutLook and I am not quite sure I am following how you work the numeric values into the code. After writing the Const olTo = 1 into the code, does the 1 get used later in the code?

Comment: In your existing code you replace the Outlook constants with the numbers, so for `.Type = olCC` you change it to `.Type = 2 ' value for olCC`. I usually add a comment at the end of the line to remind me/others what the value 2 represents.

Comment: @ChipsLetten OK I see what you are saying, I did change to the numeric value and the CC portion works now! Thank you very much for your insight, if you post a formal answer I would love to give you and Tim the credit for answering my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you reference the Outlook object library

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateEmail()

    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object
    Dim ToRecipient As Variant
    Dim CcRecipient As Variant

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(olmailitem)

    For Each ToRecipient In Array("jon.doe@aol.com")
        OlMail.Recipients.Add ToRecipient
    Next ToRecipient

    For Each CcRecipient In Array("jon.doe@aol.com")
        With OlMail.Recipients.Add(CcRecipient)
          .Type = olcc
        End With
    Next CcRecipient

    'Fill in Subject field
    OlMail.Subject = "Open Payable Receivable"


    'Add the report as an attachment
    OlMail.Attachments.Add "C:\temp\test1.xlsx"
    OlMail.Display ' <--for testing, to send use OlMail.Send

    'OlMail.Send
 End Sub
```

to add multiple CcRecipient
`In Array("jon.doe@aol.com","jon.doe@aol.com")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AUTOGENERATEEMAIL()

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strBody = "<FONT SIZE = 3>Good day all, " & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please see attached." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Pleasant Regards"

With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "Roti@hotmail.com; sall@hotmail.com; mj@hotmail.com; "
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Finance" & path
    .HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody
    .Attachments.Add ("\\Finance\Company Shared Folders\UserShares\Finance Tool\Finance Assistant Tools\Finance.xlsb")
    .Display

End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26181837)