# How to send an Excel sheet to Outlook mailbox?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an Excel document to log work done during the day to be passed to the nightshift so they are kept up-to-date with the days activites and vice versa.

The plan is to fill out the document and click a 'Send' button that will send the newly created Excel sheet to a shared Outlook folder.

My attempts have been scrapes off the web copied & tried, but to no avail.

Comment: Please post some sort of attempt so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Have it saved to a temporary file, and then send it as an attachment in an email. There are plenty of examples of that on here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630767/sending-outlook-email-with-attachment-through-vba?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it may help :)

```
Sub outMail()

Dim outApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
Dim signature As String
Dim obszar As String

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

With oMail
    .Display
End With

signature = oMail.Body

With oMail
    .To = "email@email.com"
    .CC = "email2@email.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Log work done during the day"
    .BodyFormat = 2
    .Body = "Hello" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "The newly created Excel sheet with log work done during the day " & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & signature

    'here You put directory to your file, for now its directory to file where macro is
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    'now its set to display only, if You want to send automatically put .send as below
    .Display
    '.Send

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML for the email body, you will also be able to format the mail body. Just change the file path to attach the mail. If you want to include a new line in the mail body use < br > (without space).

```
Sub StackOverflow()
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "Johnston@Stackoverflow.com"
    .Subject = "Excel Document"

    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & _
    "Hi" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
    "Here is the Excel document." & _
    .HTMLBody

    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Desktop\" & "ExcelDocument.xlsx")
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```